# Check if MySQL Row exists

Tags: php, mysql

How can I check if the table row exists and if it doesn't make a row? So far I have this:

```
$id = $user->getID();
$username = $user->username;
$check = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE nickname = '".$username."'";
$result = mysql_query($check);

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
$user->parent->mysql->query("INSERT INTO $ngtable (`id`, `namecolor`, `glowcolor`, `bubblecolor`, `bubbletext`, `bubbleglow`, `ringcolor`, `snowglow`) VALUES ('".$id."','0x','0x','0x','0x','0x','0x','0x')");
}else{
$user->parent->mysql->query("UPDATE $ngTable SET namecolor = '0x" . $arg . "' WHERE id = '" . $user->getID() . "'");
$user->sendPacket("%xt%sm%-1%0%$user->username, your name color is now: $arg%");
}
```

Comment: I believe you want to flip your `if/else` blocks, since when `if(mysql_num_rows($result))` == true, the id exists in users, so you want to do the update, else id doesn't exist in user so you need to do an insert?

Comment: If the ID is not in the table I want MySQL to insert it, if it is in the table it should update instead

Answer (score 2):

MySQL INSERT supports ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - that would be the most efficient way.

For example...

```
INSERT INTO table_name (id, foo, bar) VALUES (7, 'baz', 'bat') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE foo='baz', bar='bat'
```

Naturally this relies on your table having a unique index (a primary key will do) which your insert will cause a conflict with and thus trigger the update.

Comment: I do not understand this

Comment: @phil-lavin The code I posted will insert the row, or delete and insert a new one if one was there already. (See the comments below my answer for more detail)

Comment: `REPLACE INTO` will delete an existing row. The OP is updating only one column, so a REPLCE will lose all the data on other columns.

Comment: Fair point - deleted my earlier comment. Sounds like the INSERT with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is what's required here.

Answer (score 0):

Although you would need to set up a table constraint on the nickname to be unique, the best way might be to use the [MySQL replace syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) which does what you want in one fell swoop.

```
replace INTO 
    $ngtable 
        (`id`, `namecolor`, `glowcolor`, `bubblecolor`, `bubbletext`, `bubbleglow`, `ringcolor`, `snowglow`) 
    VALUES 
        ('".$id."','0x','0x','0x','0x','0x','0x','0x')
```

From the docs:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.
>
> MySQL uses the following algorithm for REPLACE (and LOAD DATA ... REPLACE):
>       Try to insert the new row into the table
>       While the insertion fails because a duplicate-key error occurs for a primary key or unique index:
>           Delete from the table the conflicting row that has the duplicate key value
>           Try again to insert the new row into the table

Comment: `REPLACE` will not update an existing row - it will delete it. Any existing data in the row will be lost.

Comment: @MikeW Yeah, though it does look from the code in the question like that won't be an issue has he does seem to have all the data for the row there?

Comment: For an INSERT, yes. For an update only one column is changed. Your suggestion will lose any data in other columns.